# Can I use IBOutletCollection with WatchKit?

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, iboutletcollection

I'm tring to use IBOutletCollection to connect multiple interface views. Like this one:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(WKInterfaceLabel)
        NSSet *interfaceLables;
```

But that doesn't show on interface builder, so I cannot use it. Is there any way I could use it with WatchKit Extension?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know `WKInterfaceController` doesn't support `IBOutletCollection`. If you ctrl + drag from the watch's storyboard to your `WKInterfaceController` the option for Outlet Connection doesn't show up, and it is actually disabled, so I guess it isn't supported yet:

[image]